# pandas select subset of pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

There are a few questions here on this topic, but none seem to be helpful in my case. Here's a dumbed down version of what I want:

This is the csv file of interest: http://pastebin.com/rP7tPDse

I'm creating the pivot table as:

```
piv = pd.read_csv("test.csv",delimiter = "\s+").pivot_table('z','x','y')
```

And this returns

```
y    0.0  1.0  1.3  2.0
x
0.0  1.0  5.0  NaN  4.0
1.0  3.0  4.0  NaN  6.0
1.5  NaN  NaN  7.0  NaN
2.0  3.0  5.0  NaN  7.0
```

I would like to find a slice of this array as a pivot_table, such as:

```
y    1.3  2.0
x
0.0  NaN  4.0
1.0  NaN  6.0
```

Based on the x and y values. I want to include the NaN's as well, to do processing on them later. Help much appreciated.

EDIT: updating the question to be more specific.

I'm looking to extract a pivot table that has values denoted by the column 'z' and indexed by 'x' and 'y', with the condition that:

- All x values between arbitrary xmin and xmax
- All y values between arbitrary ymin and ymax

From **piv**, as defined above, I want to do something like:

```
piv.loc[(piv.y <= 2.0) & 
(piv.y >= 1.3) & 
(piv.x >= 0.0) & 
(piv.x <= 1.2)]
```

And this would yield me the example answer, above.
Also, in the actual dataset, which I did not post here, there are many more columns. 'x', 'y' and 'z' are just some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copied dataframe, the columns were strings and rows were floats.
To get the columns as float

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(float)
```

Now you can [`pd.IndexSlice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[0:1], pd.IndexSlice[1.3:2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this fail if there are more columns? Also, how would I pick out a range? (e.g. all values that have x between [1,3] and y between [0,2])

Comment: I'm failing to understand what you want?

Comment: I've updated the question to be more specific. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, that is almost what I want! Updated my question one more time (sorry). The only thing remaining is: how can I make sure that the index slicing is happening on the specific columns I want? EDIT: nvm, it works. I thought that 'df' was not referring to pivot table already.